# which group I belong to vs to which group I belong

Tags: grammaticality, formality, speech, register, pied-piping

1. I don't know which group I belong to.
2. I don't know to which group I belong.

Which one of the sentences is true?

---

Note: An answer was given to this question when it still read "I don't know (to) which group **do** I belong (to)."

Comment: Either one could be true; I don't know which group you belong to. But I think you're asking about grammaticality. The first one has what is called a stranded preposition at the end, and the second one has what is called a pied-piped preposition at the beginning. Both are correct, both are grammatical, and both mean the same thing. You get to choose which one sounds nicer to you.

Answer (score 1):

Both are worded in the form of a question without the correct puctuation.

While the more formal old school "To which group do I belong" is a good way to form the sentence if it is truly a question, but the informal "Which group do I belong to" is much more common, though some might argue is not technically good form. In short, my suggestion is that you are using too many words, but I will also correct the above examples.

1. I don't know which group I belong to.
2. I don't know to which group I belong.

I simply removed the word 'do', from both.

Comment: +1 Mainly because the question was edited after your answer, thereby invalidating part of your answer (and having it partially make no sense).

Answer (score -1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Either one could be true; I don't know which group you belong to. But I think you're asking about grammaticality. The first one has what is called a stranded preposition at the end, and the second one has what is called a pied-piped preposition at the beginning. Both are correct, both are grammatical, and both mean the same thing. You get to choose which one sounds nicer to you.